# How can I correct my code and wrap the nav element here as shown in the photo provided?

Tags: html, css, nav

I am doing an assignment for school, and don't worry, I'm aware of how ugly this looks design wise. I wouldn't have chosen to make it look like this myself. However, I missed some points here because "NAV on schedule page does not appear stacked when in narrow screen view". Here is a link to a photo of what the nav bar is supposed to look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDe5b.png

And here is what it currently looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWdBV.png

---

And here is a photo of what the page is supposed to look like when narrowed to simulate a smartphone view, versus what it currently looks like:

Supposed to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSe62.jpg

Currently looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XE1fx.jpg

---
And here is my HTML code for this specific page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" 
        content="width=device-width, 
        initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="yogacss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>
    Yoga Schedule
</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
        <div id="header">
    <header class="content">
        <h1>
            <a href="schedule.html">Path of Light Yoga Studio</a>
        </h1>
    </header>
    </div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="classes.html">Classes</a></li>
        <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></li> 
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <main>
        <h2>
            Yoga Schedule
        </h2>
        <p>
            Mats, blocks, and blankets provided. Please arrive 
            10 minutes before your class begins. 
            Relax in our Serenity Lounge before or after your class.
        </p>
        <section class="flow">
        <h3>
            Monday — Friday
        </h3>
        <ul>
            <li>9:00am Gentle Hatha Yoga</li>
            <li>10:30am Vinyasa Yoga</li>
            <li>5:30pm Restorative Yoga</li>
            <li>7:00pm Gentle Hatha Yoga</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>
            Saturday & Sunday
        </h3>
        <ul>
            <li>10:30am Gentle Hatha Yoga</li>
            <li>Noon Vinyasa Yoga</li>
            <li>1:30pm Gentle Hatha Yoga</li>
            <li>3:00pm Vinyasa Yoga</li>
            <li>5:30pm Restorative Yoga</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
            <div id="loungehero">
                
                </div>
        </main>
<footer>
    Copyright &copy; 2020 Path of Light Yoga Studio<br>
    <a href="mailto:eli@gmail.com">Send Email</a>
</footer>
</div>
</html>
```

---

And here is my CSS code:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #3F2860;
    color: #40407A;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}
header {
    background-color: #40407A;
    background-image: url(sunrise.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    font-size: 90%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
header a:link {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header a:visited {
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header a:hover {
    color: #EDF5F5;
}
h1 {
    
}
nav {
    padding: 1em;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
}
nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
nav a:link { color: #3F2860;
    width: 40%;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    display: inline; 
}
 nav a:visited { color: #497777; 
}
 nav a:hover { color: #A26100; 
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.studio {
    font-style: italic;
}
footer {
    font-size: .60em;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    padding: 2em;
}
main {
    
}
#hero {
    
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.floatleft {

}
.clear {
    
}
.onehalf {
    
}
.onethird {
    
}

.home {
    height: 20vh;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-left: 10%;
}

.content {
    height: 20vh;
    padding-top: 2em;
    padding-left: 10%;
}

#mathero {
    background-image: url(yogamat.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    display: none;
}

#loungehero {
    background-image: url(yogalounge.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    display: none;
}

section {
}

#mobile {
    display: inline;
}

#desktop {
    display: none;

}


@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    .nav ul {
        grid-row: nowrap;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    .nav a:link {
        width: 70em;
    }
    .section {
        padding-left: 2em;
        padding-right: 2em;
    }
    #mathero, #loungehero {
        display: block;
        padding-bottom: 1em;
    }
    #flow {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    #mobile {
        display: inline;
    }
    #desktop {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .header {
        font-size: 120%;
    }
    .home {
        height: 50vh;
        padding-top: 5em;
        padding-left: 8em;
    }
    .content {
        height: 30vh;
        padding-top: 1em;
        padding-left: 8em;
    }
    #wrapper {
        margin: auto;
        width: 80%;
    }

}
```

---

Thank you so much if you can provide help, I'd be incredibly grateful. This has been frustrating me.

Comment: I would argue that the stacked nav is not clear. My first thought was "what's a home schedule"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches to do this, but as per your code structure and requirements, the simplest solution for you is:

Restructure your navigation HTML code as below :

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a> <br /> <a href="classes.html">Classes</a></li>
            <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a> <br /><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

and update your following CSS Code to get the desired result:

```
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0%;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
nav ul li {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
nav ul li:first-child {
    text-align: right;
}
nav a:link {
    color: #3F2860;
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
nav ul li:first-child a{
    color:#477677;
}
```

Note: it will work perfectly on all devices.

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked just as I needed it to. Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to set you menu up with the right infrastructure to do this, so I divided your `ul` into two. I made some changes to your css, as you'll see. You can change up the colors and contents of the menu on your own.

CSS:

```
body {
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #3F2860;
            color: #40407A;
            font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
        }
        header {
            background-color: #40407A;
            background-image: url(sunrise.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            color: white;
            font-size: 90%;
            margin-top: 30px;
            min-height: 200px;
        }
        header a:link {
            color:#FFF;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        header a:visited {
            color:#FFF;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        header a:hover {
            color: #EDF5F5;
        }
        h1 {
            
        }
        nav {
            padding: 1em;
            padding-top: 0.5em;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            text-align: right;
            background-color: white;
            margin: 0;
            padding-right: 0;
            z-index: 9999;
            width: 100%;
        }
        nav a {
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }
        nav a:link { color: #3F2860;
            width: 40%;
            padding-top: 0;
            padding-bottom: 0;
            padding-left: 1em;
            padding-right: 1em;
            display: inline; 
        }
         nav a:visited { color: #497777; 
        }
         nav a:hover { color: #A26100; 
        }

        nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0%;
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            width: 50%;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        /* New Styling */
        @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

        .rightmenu {
            text-align: left;
        }

        .rightmenu li a {
            color: green;
        }

        .leftmenu li a {
            color: blue;
        }

        nav {
            display: flex;
        }

        nav ul {
            display: block;
        }

    }

        .studio {
            font-style: italic;
        }
        footer {
            font-size: .60em;
            font-style: italic;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #wrapper {
            background-color: #F5F5F5;
            padding: 2em;
        }
        main {
            
        }
        #hero {
            
        }
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box; 
        }
        .floatleft {
        
        }
        .clear {
            
        }
        .onehalf {
            
        }
        .onethird {
            
        }
        
        .home {
            height: 20vh;
            padding-top: 2em;
            padding-left: 10%;
        }
        
        .content {
            height: 20vh;
            padding-top: 2em;
            padding-left: 10%;
        }
        
        #mathero {
            background-image: url(yogamat.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            height: 300px;
            background-size: cover;
            display: none;
        }
        
        #loungehero {
            background-image: url(yogalounge.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            height: 300px;
            background-size: cover;
            display: none;
        }
        
        section {
        }
        
        #mobile {
            display: inline;
        }
        
        #desktop {
            display: none;
        
        }
        
        
        @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
            .nav ul {
                grid-row: nowrap;
                justify-content: flex-end;
            }
            .nav a:link {
                width: 70em;
            }
            .section {
                padding-left: 2em;
                padding-right: 2em;
            }
            #mathero, #loungehero {
                display: block;
                padding-bottom: 1em;
            }
            #flow {
                flex-direction: row;
            }
            #mobile {
                display: inline;
            }
            #desktop {
                display: none;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
            .header {
                font-size: 120%;
            }
            .home {
                height: 50vh;
                padding-top: 5em;
                padding-left: 8em;
            }
            .content {
                height: 30vh;
                padding-top: 1em;
                padding-left: 8em;
            }
            #wrapper {
                margin: auto;
                width: 80%;
            }
        
        }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" 
        content="width=device-width, 
        initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="yogacss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>
    Yoga Schedule
</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
        <div id="header">
    <header class="content">
        <h1>
            <a href="schedule.html">Path of Light Yoga Studio</a>
        </h1>
    </header>
    </div>
    <nav>
    <ul class="leftmenu">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="classes.html">Classes</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="rightmenu">
        <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></li> 
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li> 
    </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <main>
        <h2>
            Yoga Schedule
        </h2>
        <p>
            Mats, blocks, and blankets provided. Please arrive 
            10 minutes before your class begins. 
            Relax in our Serenity Lounge before or after your class.
        </p>
        <section class="flow">
        <h3>
            Monday — Friday
        </h3>
        <ul>
            <li>9:00am Gentle Hatha Yoga</li>
            <li>10:30am Vinyasa Yoga</li>
            <li>5:30pm Restorative Yoga</li>
            <li>7:00pm Gentle Hatha Yoga</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>
            Saturday & Sunday
        </h3>
        <ul>
            <li>10:30am Gentle Hatha Yoga</li>
            <li>Noon Vinyasa Yoga</li>
            <li>1:30pm Gentle Hatha Yoga</li>
            <li>3:00pm Vinyasa Yoga</li>
            <li>5:30pm Restorative Yoga</li>
        </ul>
    </section>
            <div id="loungehero">
                
                </div>
        </main>
<footer>
    Copyright &copy; 2020 Path of Light Yoga Studio<br>
    <a href="mailto:eli@gmail.com">Send Email</a>
</footer>
</div>
</html>
```